# How to get apt-get source verification working?

Tags: apt-get, verification

Example (Using Debian Wheezy):

```
sudo apt-get source hello
```

Result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Need to get 705 kB of source archives.
Get:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/main hello 2.8-3 (dsc) [1287 B]
Get:2 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/main hello 2.8-3 (tar) [697 kB]
Get:3 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/main hello 2.8-3 (diff) [6598 B]                                                               
Fetched 705 kB in 8s (80.6 kB/s)                                                                                                              
gpgv: keyblock resource `/root/.gnupg/trustedkeys.gpg': file open error
gpgv: Signature made Wed Feb 13 10:30:20 2013 UTC using RSA key ID 9F1B8B32
gpgv: Can't check signature: public key not found
dpkg-source: warning: failed to verify signature on ./hello_2.8-3.dsc
dpkg-source: info: extracting hello in hello-2.8
dpkg-source: info: unpacking hello_2.8.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: unpacking hello_2.8-3.debian.tar.gz
```

The dpkg-dev and debian-keyring package is already installed.

I tried running apt-get source as user, as root, used "gpg --recv-keys 9F1B8B32" beforehand as user and as root. Nothing helped to get the downloaded sources verified.

How can I get rid of this "dpkg-source: warning: failed to verify signature" warning?

Comment: try it with `gpg --keyserver keyring.debian.org --recv-keys 9F1B8B32`?

Comment: Did not help...

Comment: Worked for me with apt-get source hello-debhelper, and I was root in root dir.

Answer (score 10):

do

```
apt-get install debian-keyring
```

to install all debian developer keyrings. It would check after that.

Comment: The dpkg-dev and debian-keyring package is already installed. Edited the original question with that information.

Comment: @user28464 that is most strange, can you try "apt-get update; apt-get install --reinstall debian-keyring"? what does "ls -l /usr/share/keyrings" return?

Comment: Unfortunately, it must read `apt-get install debian-keyring/sid` to work most of the time.

Comment: This (without /sid) worked for me on Debian Jessie

Answer (score 2):

It is `debian-keyring` you want (the `.dsc` file being checked is signed by the maintainer) but installing `debian-keyring` still leaves some plumbing to be done to make `gpg` consider the developer keys (automatically considering them would be a can of worms, which is presumably why the plumbing isn't done as part of post-install).

If it's a one-off, recheck the `.dsc` after the fetch using:

```
gpg --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/debian-maintainers.gpg --verify *.dsc
```

If you'll be grabbing several, add:

```
keyring /usr/share/keyrings/debian-maintainers.gpg
```

to your `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`; from then on, `gpg` (and `gpgv`) will consider the developer/maintainer keys for signature verification.  (If you're paranoid, you could use `/usr/share/keyrings/debian-keyring.gpg` which includes full developers but not maintainers.)

Neither approach will make the keys be considered valid, but that's probably what you want — if you obtained `debian-keyring` with a sanely configured `apt-get`/`aptitude` and *that* package's signature was checked, you can have reasonable confidence that the keys in there really belong to the developers/maintainers.

Comment: Isn't it that `apt-get source` uses `dscverify` to check signatures? `squeeze`'s manpage for `dscverify` lists `/usr/share/keyrings/debian-maintainers.gpg` as one of the places to search for the debian keyring.

Answer (score 0):

The important detail missing here is that you need the keyring from `sid`, not the keyring from `stable`, because only sid's keyring carries all the developers.  Notice the `/sid` in next line:

```
apt-get install debian-keyring/sid
```

To get `sid` you usually need a line like following in `/etc/apt/source.list`:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ sid main
```

(And don't forget to `apt-get update` afterwards.)

But beware!  If `sid` sits in your `sources.list` your system tends to morph into `sid` against your will.  To prevent that, add a line to `/etc/apt/apt.conf` which looks like:

```
APT::Default-Release "stable";
```

(There are gazillions of other ways to prevent `sid`, this one is the most easy one I know.)

Notes:

- Clue to this solution was found at http://debian.distrosfaqs.org/debian-user/signature-of-wheezys-linux-source-package/
- Before I found this I stumbled upon thousands of pages telling you to simply fetch the missing key from a keyserver: **Never do such a stupid thing to verify a signature!** If a MitM was able to send you a faked package, the same one is able to send you a faked answer of the keyserver as well.  Hence a key pulled from a keyserver just is plain snakeoil.  (And in a security context believing in "snakeoil" is the probably most stupid thing you can do.)

Answer (score 0):

Judging from "gpgv: keyblock resource `/root/.gnupg/trustedkeys.gpg': file open error" line, you must be running into [`gpg`'s bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=706919). In the end `apt-get source` runs `gpg` with `--no-option` switch. Which fails if no homedir (`~/.gnupg`) exists. One can remedy this with: `gpg -k`. More details [here](https://serverfault.com/a/590604/162443).